# Tkinter label image turns blank

Tags: python, tkinter

This code I am writing is supposed to add a picture every time a button is clicked, but after I do more than one the last picture disappears.

```
import tkinter

suits = ["club", "heart", "diamond", "spade"]
faces = ["jack", "queen", "king"]


def deal():
    global value
    global card
    global deck
    value, card = deck.pop(0)
    print(deck)
    return card

def image():
    global count
    tkinter.Label(root, image=deal()).grid(row=1, column=count)
    count += 1

root = tkinter.Tk()

deck = []

for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in suits:
        pic = "cards/{}_{}.png".format(x, y)
        img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=pic)
        deck.append((x, img))

    for z in faces:
        pic = "cards/{}_{}.png".format(z, y)
        img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=pic)
        deck.append((10, img))

value, card = deck.pop(0)
count = 0

tkinter.Button(root, text="Click me", command=image).grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

How should I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you call `deal` again, the `PhotoImage` stored in `card` is replaced by another one, so it is garbage collected and it disappears. To prevent that, you can create a list of pictures:

```
import tkinter

suits = ["club", "heart", "diamond", "spade"]
faces = ["jack", "queen", "king"]
pictures = []

def deal():
    global value
    global card
    global deck
    value, card = deck.pop(0)
    print(deck)
    return card

def image():
    global count
    tkinter.Label(root, image=deal()).grid(row=1, column=count)
    count += 1

root = tkinter.Tk()

deck = []

for x in range(1, 11):
    for y in suits:
        pic = "cards/{}_{}.png".format(x, y)
        img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=pic)
        pictures.append(img)
        deck.append((x, img))

    for z in faces:
        pic = "cards/{}_{}.png".format(z, y)
        img = tkinter.PhotoImage(file=pic)
        pictures.append(img)
        deck.append((10, img))

value, card = deck.pop(0)
count = 0

tkinter.Button(root, text="Click me", command=image).grid(row=0, column=0)
root.mainloop()
```